# Wordpress - Restrict users in backend to certain categories

Tags: php, wordpress, restriction

I'm looking to modify Wordpress with a plugin hopefully that will restrict users edit only certain categories, posts and widgets. Does anyone know of anything that may help?

Comment: Google might? Or the WP plugin repository? Let me do a quick check...

Comment: Googling `wordpress restrict users backend` yields some promising results. Check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always used this module to help with restrictions and permissions http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

Comment: Thanks! I think I may be able to work with this. Can I restrict access to specific widgets too or no?

Comment: Yes I believe you can - it allows pretty much full control over everything.